# Подтверждения номера по СМС через приложение windows forms c#

Tags: c#, winforms

Подскажите способы реализации подтверждения номера по СМС через приложение windows forms c#?
Информации по реализации на windows forms мало, в основном ASP.NET.

Есть форма, где пользователь вводит свой номер телефона, который необходимо подтвердить (отправка смс на указанный номер -> ввод кода из СМС).

Comment: вам просто нужно найти сервис, который предоставляет такую услугу и найти документацию к его API

Comment: Да на самом деле без разницы ASP или винформы, хоть консоль. Взаимодействие с смс будет одно,а там уж куда хотите его подключайте

Comment: вот для примера бесплатный сервис для смс с API: https://www.smsmode.com/en/api-sms/

Comment: Эм... А зачем? WinForms - это десктоп приложение, то есть, клиент-приложение, которое должно подключаться к удаленному серверу, а уже тот, проверять номера и так далее. Если у вас эта логика в клиенте, то зачем человеку проверять свой же номер, для самого себя? Вы скажете "чтобы вписать в базу валидный номер", ок, а где база? Если рядом с приложением, то это опять же, все "имущество" этого пользователя, он в праве хоть напрямую залезть в базу и там написать, все, что хочет, без ваших проверок, ибо это его, на его компе. Так что, эти подтверждения через СМС в клиенте... Бред.

Comment: Вам нужен сервер с базой данных, полностью защищенной и недоступной пользователю. В противном случае такая двухфакторка не имеет никакого смысла. Именно поэтому вы примеры для сервера нашли, а для десктопных приложений - нет.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Может и неправильное решение, но работает.

Решил через звонок бота с помощью https://zadarma.com/ru/

1. Генерирую рандомом четырехзначное число (от 1000 до 9999).
2. С помощью Задармы звоню и робот произносит код, который я передаю в параметре.
3. Сравниваю сгенерированное рандомом число и введеное пользователем в textbox.

   ```
        Random rnd = new Random();

        value = rnd.Next(1000, 9999);

        var zadarma = new ZadarmaApi("Key", "Secret");

        var parameters = new SortedDictionary<string, string>()
            {
                {"caller_id", "74951234567"},
                {"to", "79101234567"},
                {"code", value.ToString()},
                {"lang", "ru"}
            };
        var response = zadarma.Call("/v1/request/checknumber/", parameters);
        var str = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
   ```